# Extracting certain a href values from any domain in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm writing a Perl program to extract values from `<td>` and `<a href>` till `</a>` and most likely I want result after `/domain/` as mentioned in the HTML source code. I need to use this kind of information in the future more often, so please guide me.

My question: where am I going wrong and why? I read many regex pages, but they didn't help at all.

## Snippet from Perl program

Regex 1:

```
while ($response =~ m/<td><a href=\"\/domain\/(.*?)\/dns">(.*?)/g )
```

Regex 2:

```
while($response =~  s/((?:href|domain))\=\"([^{].*?)/ig ) {
```

## HTML source code

```
<td><b>‐</b></td><td><div class="">Google LLC < / div >< / td>< td >< b> ‐< /b >< /td >< /tr >< tr class="data-row " >< td> 5 < /td> < td>< a href= "/domain/rate-limited-proxy-66-249-91-229.google.com/dns "> rate-limited-proxy-66-249-91-229.google.com < / a> < /td>
```

Comment: Use a html parser to get at the data you need, not regular expressions.

Comment: [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) for HTML parsing in general, [HTML::TableExtract](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TableExtract) for tables.

Comment: Is that really the HTML you are trying to parse? I looks ill formatted: spaces between  slash and closing tag name? That would make it tricky if not consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first regex is almost working, minus the missing spaces to account for in the HTML source and an unescaped quote at the end.
I've marked out the additions below with ^:

```
m/< td>< a href= \"\/domain\/(.*)\/dns \">(.*?)/g
   ^    ^       ^                     ^^
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/<\s*a\s+.*?href\s*=\s*".*?domain\/(.*?)".*?>/`
```

Should extract everything after `domain/`, up to the next `"` found within the `href` of an `<a>`.

Not sure how you should manage the regex modifiers, within your code, tho. An `m` and `g` might be needed, and an `i` could be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you so much, this remark made me curious so I looked code again (800+ lines) I found, I was handling regex modifier incorrectly, I changed and tweaked few lines, it started to work exactly like it suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it most possibly you meant '$response' should be the extract result? if so, let's have variable for data source enclosed by quotes in Perl notation `qq{}`

```
 '$htmlsrc=qq{<td><b>‐</b></td><td><div class="">Google LLC < / div ><
 / td>< td >< b> ‐< /b >< /td >< /tr >< tr class="data-row " >< td> 5
 < /td> < td>< a href=
 "/domain/rate-limited-proxy-66-249-91-229.google.com/dns ">
 rate-limited-proxy-66-249-91-229.google.com < / a> </td>"}
while
 (@response = $htmlsrc =~ /.+?< *a href= *"\/domain\/(.+?)".*>/) {print
 @response}

 rate-limited-proxy-66-249-91-229.google.com/dns
```

extract result is in 'response' array but in this case only has one member corresponding to number of the captured group